# How to create custom blocks in RMarkdown?

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, bookdown

In [RMarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/), I know I can type something like this:

````
```{r}
sum <- 1 + 1
```
````

To create a block to be evaluated inside the R session for the currently processed `.Rmd` document. I know there are others where the label inside `{<label>}` changes and triggers a different behavior. Fx, [Bookdown]{https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#equations} defines: `{theorem}` and others.

#### What I need

I wanna be able to create my own block and execute certain code to handle its content:

````
```{myblock}
This text will appear styled different (for example)
```
````

I do not need to create a new block for styling text, the one above is just an example. How can I achieve this customization?

Comment: Did you have a look at the source code https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/engine.R and the description https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html? I think you can manipulate the code to your own needs.

Comment: @J_F Your comment represents a valid answer. Please post an answer so I can sign off! Thanks

Comment: I just wrote a section on this topic in the R Markdown Cookbook: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-engine.html I hope it could be useful to you. Please feel free to let me know you have any comments or questions about this section. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find information of supported engines in the [official documentation of the `knitr` package](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html).

Also have a look at [the code](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/engine.R).

Now you can manipulate the code to your own needs, build the package and use it with your own needs.